# Ruby Hash .keys and .values, safe to assume same order?

Tags: ruby, hash

Rudimentary irb testing suggests that Ruby Hash returns `.keys` and `.values` in matching order. Is it safe to assume that this is the case?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. According to the [Ruby Docs for Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted." So you should always get the same order for a hash if it is created in the same way.

Comment: Note this is true for 1.9, but not necessarily for 1.8 and earlier

Comment: In 1.8 you can rectify with keys = h.keys; values = h.values_at *keys

Answer (score 9):

Depends on which Ruby version you are running.
Up to 1.8, enumeration was not insertion-ordered. Starting with 1.9, it will enumerate keys and values according to insertion order so, yes, it is safe to assume as long as you are running 1.9.